# Rolling (moving) window linear regression - extract residuals

Tags: raster, r, regression, residuals

I want to perform linear regression with a rolling (moving) window with size 5 using raster data.

I tried a code using the `raster` package and the function `localFun`, and when I am trying to export the residuals I am getting the following error: `Error in setValues(x, value) : values must be numeric, logical or factor`. Here is the code:

```
library(raster)

ntl = raster("path/ntl.tif") # dependent variable
tirs = raster("path/tirs.tif") # independent variable
tirs_aggr = resample(tirs, ntl, method = 'bilinear')

rfun1 <- function(x, y, ...) {
  d <- na.omit(data.frame(x, y))
  if (nrow(d) < 5) return(NA)
  m <- lm(y~x, data = d)
  # return intercept
  coefficients(m)[1]
}

rfun2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
  d <- na.omit(data.frame(x, y))
  if (nrow(d) < 5) return(NA)
  m <- lm(y~x, data = d)
  # return slope
  coefficients(m)[2]
}

rfun3 <- function(x, y, ...) {
  d <- na.omit(data.frame(x, y))
  if (nrow(d) < 5) return(NA)
  m <- lm(y~x, data = d)$residuals # doesn't work
  # return residuals
  # residuals(m) or m$residuals # doesn't work
}

ff = localFun(ntl, tirs_aggr, ngb = 5, fun = rfun1)
ff2 = localFun(ntl, tirs_aggr, ngb = 5, fun = rfun2)
ff3 = localFun(ntl, tirs_aggr, ngb = 5, fun = rfun3) # returns error
```

My question is this: How can I extract the coefficients and the residuals as raster layers from a moving window linear regression?

The data:

```
ntl = raster(ncols=116, nrows=98, xmn=509587.9392, xmx=550187.9392, ymn=161637.6238, ymx=195937.6238, crs='+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs')

tirs = raster(ncols=409, nrows=344, xmn=509600, xmx=550500, ymn=161700, ymx=196100, crs='+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [package's code](https://github.com/rspatial/raster/blob/master/R/localFun.R#L13). It's not possible to return a raster with 2 or more layers:

```
out <- raster(x)
```

Since your matrix is 5x5, you can get up to 25 values from `m$residuals` or `residuales(m)`, which is incompatible with `raster` package.

You can do it *not directly* with terra. I give you an example:

```
library(terra)

# example rasters
ntl <- rast(nrows=18, ncols=36)
tirs_aggr <- ntl

set.seed(123)
values(ntl) <- rnorm(n=ncell(ntl))
values(tirs_aggr) <- rnorm(n=ncell(ntl))

#get focal values for each window
fntl <- focalValues(ntl, w=5, row=1, nrows=nrow(ntl), fill=NA)
ftirs_aggr <- focalValues(tirs_aggr, w=5, row=1, nrows=nrow(ntl), fill=NA)

# funtion to compute all you want
rfun_total <- function(x) {
  x1 <- x[1:(length(x)/2)]
  y1 <- x[((length(x)/2)+1):length(x)]
  d <- na.omit(data.frame(x1, y1))
  
  result <- rep(NA, length.out = 27)
  names(result) <- c('inter','x',paste0('res',1:25))
  
  if (nrow(d) >= 5){
    m <- lm(y1~x1, data = d)
    # return slope
    result[1:(length(m$residuals)+2)] <- c(coefficients(m),m$residuals)
    
  }
  
  result
}

# concatenate results and apply function
result <- apply(cbind(fntl,ftirs_aggr), MARGIN = 1, FUN = rfun_total)

final_raster <- rast(ntl, nlyrs=27)

rlist <- apply(result, 1, function(x) setValues(ntl,x))

rast(rlist)

# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 18, 36, 27  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
# extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
# source(s)   : memory
# names       :      inter,          x,      res1,      res2,      res3,      res4, ... 
# min values  : -0.5300309, -0.8214684, -2.699939, -2.736957, -2.534735, -2.648687, ... 
# max values  :  0.7583305,  0.6152796,  3.283922,  3.099785,  3.067819,  3.044425, ...
```

Also, you can add your need to this [thread](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/318). I find you placed a good point here

Finally, with this example you computed the linear model once, no need to do it so many times as you have been doing so far

Comment: Your code works just fine. I just need to understand one thing. The moving window regression is a local-like regression (in a sense). So I was expecting the residuals raster to be similar to what I would get if I was to to conduct GWR (i.e., one raster file for the residuals). Why your code has 25 rasters residuals? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: @Nikos A residual is the difference between the observed and fitted value. A 5x5 moving window regression takes 25 values (5 rows x 5 columns) to fit the model, hence 25 observations, 25 fitted values and 25 residuals

Comment: I am still trying to understand this so bear with me. Suppose I run GWR. The output of the algorithm is one image for the intercept, one for the slope and one for the residuals, even though GWR fits way more local models compared to the moving window. Am I right so far? Here is an example using GWR and the outputs (https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/44975_0342ec49f925426fa16ebcdc28210118.html). Although I understand your logic, I still don't understand why in GWR I can export a single image for the residuals and in your code I cannot.

Comment: It seems to me that the logic behind GWR and the rolling window regression is the same (regarding the outputs).

Comment: You said it: *one for the residuals*. Residuals are as many observations you have. In the link you shared the example plots the residuals in two ways. If you want to get coefficients + one more layer, get R^2 or another model performance metric